# Why can't I remove folder with DEL?

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

I delete folder by batch command.

```
c:\test>del 20161010
c:\test\20161010\*,are you sure (Y/N)? y
```

Why does it show `20161010\*` and the folder does not get removed after pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>?

Comment: `del` deletes files, you need to `rd` the folder.

Comment: thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DEL` only delete files, so you need `RD` after the `DEL`. `RD` stands for `RMDIR`, which means **R**e**m**ove **Dir**ectory.

---

```
del /f /s /q 20161010\*.*
rd 20161010
```

Flags definition:

- `/f`orce removal
- `/s`ubdirectories removal
- `/q`uiet removal

---

Or simply:

```
rd /s /q 20161010
```

Flag definition:

- `/s`ubdirectories removal
- `/q`uiet removal

Comment: @Peggy oh. I forget that.